# VSCode API: watch activities on workspace folders and sub-folders

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using `createFileSystemWatcher()` and `onDidChange()` to watch my workspace, but the watch is limited to root directory. I want to be able to watch activities in my sub directories too.

I will appreciate suggestions to fix it or recommend another function to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File system watchers are **not** limited to the root directory. Most likely you're using a glob pattern that looks like something like this:

```
*.txt
```

What you want instead is something like this:

```
**/*.txt
```

See also: [the docs for `GlobPattern`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#GlobPattern).

> `**` to match any number of path segments, including none

VSCode API usage example:

```ts
let watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("**/*.txt");
watcher.onDidChange(uri => console.log("change to " + uri));
```